# What's the equivalent -webkit-gradient of this CSS?

Tags: html, css, webkit

The style needs to be backward compatible.

Tried googling `-webkit-gradient` syntax and figure it out myself, but can't find the document......

So, what's the equivalent `-webkit-gradient` of this CSS:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #E0E0E0 0%, #E0E0E0 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 11%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%),
            -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F9FCF6 0%, #BBE6BF 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go. `-webkit-gradient` was only used in Chrome 4-9 and Safari 4-5. I'm surprised that it's still supported in the Safari 9:

```
background:
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(224,224,224,1)), color-stop(10%, rgba(224,224,224,1)), color-stop(11%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0))),
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(249,252,246,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(187,230,191,1)));
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/c44pkL3e/)

Answer (score 6):

The `-webkit-` is a hack for the Webkit Browser engine. In this case, applied to the linear-gradient CSS property.

Usually, the first thing we must have in mind when using CSS3 is that some old browsers could not support this "new" property (or many others).. So we use the common background always, covering the legacy engines simply.

Together with the property and the `-webkit-` hack, we have hacks for another old browser engines like Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari and Opera.

Take a look at this example

```
.some-class{

    /* Fallback (could use .jpg/.png alternatively) */
    background-color: red;

    /* SVG fallback for IE 9 (could be data URI, or could use filter) */
    background-image: url(fallback-gradient.svg); 

    /* Safari 4, Chrome 1-9, iOS 3.2-4.3, Android 2.1-3.0 */
    background-image:
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(red), to(#f06d06));

    /* Safari 5.1, iOS 5.0-6.1, Chrome 10-25, Android 4.0-4.3 */
    background-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);

    /* Firefox 3.6 - 15 */
    background-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);

    /* Opera 11.1 - 12 */
    background-image:
    -o-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);

    /* Opera 15+, Chrome 25+, IE 10+, Firefox 16+, Safari 6.1+, iOS 7+, Android 4.4+ */
    background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, red, #f06d06);

}
```

You can see more explanations at:
https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

And:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

The new standard is to use `background-image: linear-gradient()`.

The following browser versions (or later) support the new 'un-prefixed' version of `background-image: linear-gradient()`:

> Chrome: 26
>   Safari: 6.1
>   Firefox: 16
>   Opera: 15
>   IE: 10
>   Android: 4.4
>   iOS: 7.0

If you want to learn more about CSS Gradients, and the new 'un-prefixed' syntax, I'd recommend having a [read of this CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/).